# selecting keys which are not in another table takes forever

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a query like this:

```
select key, name from localtab where key not in (select key from remotetab);
```

**The query takes forever, and I don't understand why.**

`localtab` is local table, and `remotetab` is a remote table in another server. `key` is an `int` column which has a unique index in both tables. When I query the both tables separately, it takes just a few seconds.

Comment: *"and remotetab is a remote table in another server. "* There's your problem. For a remote query like that, the *entire* table will need to be transferred from the remote instance to the local instance, and then the filtering will be performed against the temporary object created from that transfer (which would most likely be a work table created in `tempdb`).

Comment: okay, but a standalone `select * from remotetab` does take just a few seconds (and all data is transferred in this case). We talk of about 100.000 records.

Comment: Could be that there will be one transfer and scan per row in `localtab`, rather than 1 transfer and then scan the table for all rows in `localtab`. This is why what vvvv4d suggests can have very different performance. Also, as I mentioned, the *entire* table is transferred, so not just the value of the column `key`, but *all* the columns.

Comment: ah okay! Yes, I assumed that there would be just ONE transfer of the remote table! But it seems this assumption is not true. Any other idea without using a temp table?

Comment: *"Any other idea without using a temp table?"* Temporary tables are often the way the go here. Otherwise you'd need to look at a method of replicating the data from the remote instance to the local one, and then the (local) instance can perform adequate lookup operations.

Comment: OK. I just assumed that the optimizer would be clever enough to first load the remote data and then to continue. Do you know why this is not the case?

Comment: Asking how SQL Server performs a linked server query is a *very* different question, and isn't suited for Stack Overflow. YOu'd be better off asking about that on [dba.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a solution without using temporary tables.

By using a `left join` instead of `not in (select ...)`, you can massively speed up the query. Like this:

```
select l.key, l.name
from  localtab l left join remotetab r on l.key = r.key
where r.key is null ;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is **much** faster and it works without temporary table! Seems that the optimizer is handling a `left join` different to the `in` clause. I will mark your post as the answer , because it needs no temporary table. The other answer is also good, though, maybe has even more speed.

Answer (score 5):

Linked Severs have terrible performance. Get the data you need to the local server and do the majority of the hard work and processing there instead of a mix of local and remote in a single query.

`select` remotetab into a temp table

`select [key] into  #remote_made_local from remotetab`

Use the #temp table when doing the where clause filtering and use `exists` instead of `in` for better performance

`select a.[key], a.name from localtab a where not exists (select 1 from #remote_made_local b where b.[key] = a.[key] )`

Vs doing

`select [key], name from localtab where key not in (select [key] from #remote_made_local)`

Comment: For added benefit, it would be a good idea to put an index on the `key` column on the temporary table. Also, `key` needs delimit identifying, as `KEY` is a reserved keyword. Ideally, such words should not be used for object names.